# To stop and resume the job process between specific timings

Tags: shell-script

I need to run the job process which is going to change the Replication factor of HDFS files from 3 to 1. This job should run only between specific timings say between 10PM to next day 6AM. Could anyone help how to achieve this scenario.

I know we can use `kill -STOP <PID>` and `kill -CONT <PID>`

please correct me whether the command is correct and how to stop the loop once it reaches the specific time.

Comment: have u tried scheduling cron?

Comment: Nope. I am preparing the script. Bit confused on the process stop and resume process.

Comment: u can create a script to stop/start the process. then schedule the cron job respectively...

Comment: You mean. a separate script for hdfs commands and start and stop process?

Comment: one script with arguments as stop/start/status... as such like startup scripts...

Comment: Ok.. For start time I can use `start_tm=$(date +%H:%M:%S)` . So the job starts exactly @10PM and job should run till 6AM.. Now how can I get 6AM, do I need to hardcore the time?. this is where I struck

Comment: On other hand, I feel stop and resume will not have any logic. So I am planning to use the timings and execute as much as hdfs command to changes RF to 1 (approx. 5000 files ). and kill the process.